# Batch - get tag value from XML file

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file

I have this following XML file called "test.xml"

how can I get "Agent-name-8181818" value from "ragent-name" tag into a variable within a batch file?

```
<ragent>
    <type>ragent</type>
    <logger>
        <loglevel>log_warning</loglevel>
        <logger-dir>.</logger-dir>
    </logger>
    <additional-config>
        <logger-level>log_warning</logger-level>
    </additional-config>
    <configuration-info ts="26-02-2018_15-31-54">
        <apply-config-now>false</apply-config-now>
        <manual-settings-activation>Automatic</manual-settings-activation>
        <ragent-name ts="26-02-2018_15-31-54">Agent-name-8181818</ragent-name>
        <site ts="26-02-2018_15-31-54">site</site>
    </configuration-info>
</ragent>
```

Comment: The better option is to use Jscript, Vbscript or Powershell. All have native capability to read and write xml files.  The `xpath.bat` program posted below is actually a hybrid batch file that calls out to jscript to do its work.

Comment: @Squashman  can you give an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [**xpath.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat) (does not require external binaries , just uses built-in windows capabilities):

```
call xpath test.xml "*//configuration-info/ragent-name"
```

to assign result to a variable:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('call xpath test.xml "*//configuration-info/ragent-name"') do set "reagent=%%#"
```

Answer (score 3):

As a batch-file line,

```
FOR /f "tokens=3delims=<>" %%a IN ('findstr "ragent-name" "q49011270.txt"') DO echo %%a
```

Where `q49011270.txt` is the file containing your data.

Naturally, you could assign the result to a variable instead of `echo`ing it...

Answer (score 1):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//ragent-name/text()" file.xml
```

Check http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Replaced `xmllint` by `xmlstarlet` (usable on windows)

Comment: Unfortunately, I had difficulty using xmlstarlet inside a batch file especially when the xml file has namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You may solve this and other similar problems using the lookup capabilities of SETX command:

```
for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('setx /F test.xml dummyVar /R 0^,2 ragent-name /D "<>"') do set "ragent=%%a" & goto continue
:continue
echo %ragent:~0,-1%
```

In this command:

```
setx /F test.xml dummyVar /R 0^,2 ragent-name /D "<>"
```

- **/F test.xml** is the file to process.
- **dummyVar** is a required variable.
- **/R 0,2 ragent-name** specify to search for "ragent-name" token in the file and, after found, return the token placed in the same line (0) and 2 tokens to right.
- **/D "<>"** indicate that tokens delimiters are "<" and ">" characters, *besides* spaces and tabs.

This method allows to extract tokens in lines above or below, or at left or right, from a target token in a very simple way. The only inconvenience is that the **dummyVar** variable remains in the environment with the value of the token found.

Further details at [this post](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5083).

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=><  " %%a IN ('TYPE config.xml ^| FIND "<connectionString>"') DO SET CONNECTION_STRING=%%a
```

- config.xml is the path of the files
- connectionString is tag id
- connection_string is the variable name which you want to assign1

Answer (score 0):

With the XML/HTML/JSON-parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('
  xidel -s test.xml -e "var:=//ragent-name" --output-format^=cmd
') DO %A
```

Output:

```
SET var=Agent-name-8181818
```